# Home network firewall with monitoring and alerts

Tags: router, firewall

I have more than a few computers behind my home wireless router which only has the most basic firewall. I also run Windows 7, OSX, Ubuntu so trying to buy firewall software for each OS and running machine is going to require too much maintenance.

I'd like to put something preferably before the router to manage all firewall aspects but I'd also like it to have a webpage I can hit for reports/alert management etc. If I can put it between the router + cable modem then the router can still act as DHCP/Wireless etc.

I have a Netgear WNDR3300 - not sure it has enough firewall features to be much use and no easy management/log of what is going on. It's not DD-WRT compatible.

The concept I'm shooting for is what you'd get if you purchased a personal firewall product to install directly on your machine - those alerts and intrusion attempt reporting are great.

Comment: The question was answered, accepted, and everyone was content. Why close it hours later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there specific securiy features you're looking for other than a management console and logging? Many home routers can provide this functionality to varying degrees, but dedicated security appliances are generally geared towards the buisness market (expensive).

One option I can suggest is making your own. Place a machine as a gatewayto your LAN (probably need 2 NICs), and install the firewall/security package of your choice. One I've had good luck with is [untangle](http://www.untangle.com).

Comment: PFSense is one that I've had good luck with as well.

Comment: Intrusion detection being the primary focus second then being anti-virus. I was concerned with the cost for business appliances but the home machine is a great idea. thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Plus you get a fun project this way!